# Root user denied insert on specific column in MySQL via SQL Server LinkedServer

Tags: mysql, sql-server, insert, linked-server

I'm trying to insert a record from an SQL Server into a MySQL instance that's connected as a linked server.

Here's basically what I'm doing:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER,
        'SELECT         
        id,
        claimed         
        FROM MySQLTable;'
    )
    SELECT
        Id,
        '0'--claimed            
    FROM
        MSSQLTable
```

And I'm getting this error:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKED_SERVER" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]" because of column "claimed". The user did not have permission to write to the column.

The linked server is currently configured to use the root user on the MySQL database and I've checked the privileges using GRANT and they seem fine:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '******' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

The 'claimed' column is an enum column defined as "enum('1','0')". I have a feeling that it's the enum aspect that's messing things up, but I don't know why.

I use a similar process to insert data elsewhere so I know that it should work in principle, but I just can't figure out why this column is being such a pain!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is a known issue with older versions of MySQL linked servers and OPENQUERY isn't the right tool for the job. Instead I rewrote the query to use EXEC (INSERT...) AT [LINKED_SERVER], and it worked like a charm.

This syntax is available from SQL Server 2005 onwards.

The more you know...